# Working around a disabled shell_exec()

Tags: php, magento, controller, dispatcher

I have these lines:

activate module in etc/modules/Becker_Tecdoc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Becker_Tecdoc>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Becker_Tecdoc>
 </modules>
</config>
```

becker/tecdoc/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <modules>
            <Becker_Tecdoc>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Becker_Tecdoc>
        </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <tecdoc>
                <use>Standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Becker_Tecdoc</module>
                    <frontName>tecdoc</frontName>
                </args>
            </tecdoc>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

becker/tecdoc/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Becker_Tecdoc_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction(){
        die();
    }
 }
?>
```

When I call in browser :
http://auto-complet.ro/shop/tecdoc/index/index
or
http://auto-complet.ro/shop/index.php/tecdoc/index/index

I get 404 error...

My system.log shows this error:

```
ERR (3): Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons  
in /home/autoco/public_html/shop/cron.php on line 65
```

My provider doesn't want to unblock shell_exec...

How can I fix this?

My magento is Community 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

The error in `system.log` is unrelated to your controller `404`ing.  You need to fix some capitalization issues.

- The folders `app/code/local/becker/tecdoc` should be `app/code/local/Becker/Tecdoc`
- Your controller's use statement `<use>Standard</use>` should be `<use>standard</use>`

The error in your `system.log` is coming from the `cron.php`, which wouldn't be used when loading a controller.  You shouldn't be seeing this error as Magento checks if `shell_exec` is disabled before trying to execute it

```
$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;

// later

} else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
    $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
    $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
    shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
    exit;
}

// later still

if ($isShellDisabled) {
    Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
}
```

You may want to try manually setting `$isShellDisabled` to `true` if it's having issues detecting it.